# Is there a way to associate instance of component to many selectors in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-services, angular2-directives

In Angular 2, I often see that every selector is creating an instance of a component.

Problem: I'm showing a performance chart in a card, where performance data is fetched using REST API calls for every 2 seconds. With respect to screen resolution change, cards position will be changed which is achieved through `*ngIf` directive. Here there are 2 components in memory firing duplicate API calls.

Possible solutions, I thought of are as below,

1. Making components lighter : Gather data via single rest and add subscription in service level, send crafted data back to both components. This is not much easy in my case, as because there are some wrappers to component class performing beacon activities.
2. Having 2 identical components which extends the class, where class access info from service or directly subscribes to an observable. I don't feel this as good design.

I'm looking for something better. Is there a way to add as below,
Parent Component html has,

```
<app-child></app-child>
<app-child></app-child>
```

Internally both app-child referring to same component class `ChildComponent`.

I'm newbie to angular please help me with your ideas, thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you need two of the same component here, if it is just for styling purposes as mentioned in the post, try managing the siutation by using ngStyle or ngClass, instead of overcomplicating things.

Comment: If you really need to use ngIf consider moving logic that fetches data to a service that is used by multiple components also you need to properly clean up any subscriptions inside ngDestroy or just use async pipe

Comment: Im working on a feature where on pinning cards , Card should be shown at top of page. on scrolling down those cards are also expected to be shown again. So 2 card instance will be in memory - how can we avoid this.